# AWS2 SSO Configuration error after installing aws2 cli on MacOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-sdk

For MacOS user who is installing the AWS CLI v2 and attempting to use with AWS SSO, you might see "An error occurred (InvalidClientException) when calling the StartDeviceAuthorization operation:"

If so, the solution is below.

Answer (score 8):

You need to ingress the URL with "start"

Example: https://alias.awsapps.com/start

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For those who have install aws2 and having trouble with SSO cli, ensure that after you've installed the aws2, remove the sso directory in your ~/.aws directory and re-rerun aws2 configure sso. If not, that will return "An error occurred (InvalidClientException) when calling the StartDeviceAuthorization operation:"

And also, ensure your ~/.aws/config file looks like this

```
[profile default]
sso_start_url = https://someurlhere.awsapps.com/start
sso_region = us-east-2
sso_account_id = XXXXXXX
sso_role_name = AAAAA
region = us-east-2
output = json
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the properties of your profile defined in `~/.aws/config` don't have any comments similar to the example below.

```
[profile my-sso-prod]
sso_start_url = https://my-sso.awsapps.com/start # don't forget the /start part!
```

When I removed the text after (and including) `#`, everything worked.